# Disable Keyboard Input On Userform Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have Userform with 79 Comboboxes which are populated with all the same values 1-5.  As of now if a user hits a keystroke by mistake i get an error. because after combobox change it creates a calculation because it does not recognize character input.  so what i have done now is changed the combobox to fmStyleDropDownList, which works for only adding only items listed in combobox, the problem now is that after combobox change event i do not have a if statement to capture a 0 if is inputed.  That would not be a problem if i didnt have about 3000 comboboxes throughout my project,  so my question is how can i either hide the item 0 in the combobox (if i remove 0, the calculation automatically places a 0 in the placement of the combobox in order for the calculation to work) or if a can add a control to userform if any of the comboboxes text equals 0 then frm?whatever.show.

```
 Dim ctrl As Control
 For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
 If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.ComboBox Then
    With ctrl
        .AddItem "1"
        .AddItem "2"
        .AddItem "3"
        .AddItem "4"
        .AddItem "5"
        .AddItem "0"


    End With
End If
Next ctrl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test the key input in the combobox keypress event.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'Test for zero being pressed.
    If KeyAscii = 48 Then
        'If we get a zero entered, change it to nothing.
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there away to add this as if any combobox on form as each form has about 79 comboboxga and 79 comboboxna and have about 70-90 forms with all the same comboboxes, because going to each box and adding this would take alot of time, but will do it if need to be

Comment: @INOH  Are your combo boxes in arrays?

Comment: This is how i setup my comboboxes, created userform, added all my comboboxes then on userform initialize i added this code up above

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to make an event that would cover all controls. Since you now have the way to handle the zero input,  I would open another question specif to having one event that covers all controls of a certain type.

Comment: Thanks for the help, much apppreciated